# Is the ability Steward of the Great Beyond like a permanent Detect Teleporation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, wizard, summoning, teleportation

The arcane discovery [**steward of the great beyond**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-discoveries/arcane-discoveries-paizo/steward-of-the-great-beyond) says

> Whenever a creature attempts to use a teleportation effect or summon a  creature within 30 feet of you, you may attempt to block the effect. Make an opposed caster level check (1d20 + caster level) as an immediate action. If the check succeeds, the spell or effect fails and is wasted; otherwise, it is unaffected.

Does the wizard still have to identify if someone uses a teleportation effect or attempts to summon a creature, or is this like the *D&D 3.5* power [*detect teleportation*](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Detect_Teleportation) except that it's always on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The special ability [steward of the great beyond](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-discoveries/arcane-discoveries-paizo/steward-of-the-great-beyond)—a [wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard) [arcane discovery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-discoveries)—grants even less knowledge about the teleportation effect than the *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* nomad power [*detect teleportation*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/psionicPowersDtoF.html#detect-teleportation) [clairsentience] (*XPH* 92), but the wizard needn't identify the teleportation effect that the wizard's attempting to stop.

The only thing the wizard *does* know due to the discovery is that, unless the wizard acts, a teleportation effect will be used or a creature will be summoned somewhere within 30 ft. of the wizard. The wizard doesn't know who's attempting to employ the effect or summon the creature, what the effect is or what the summoned creature will be, or (in contrast to the *detect teleportation* power) even a vague indication of *where* the teleportation effect was created or where the creature summoning is occurring (except that it's within 30 ft., of course).

Thus, essentially, the wizard's [head-up display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display) says *Either a teleportation effect is being attempted within 30 ft. of you or a creature will be summoned within 30 ft. of you. Do you want to take an immediate action to attempt to prevent the teleportation effect or the creature summoning?* No additional information is provided about the teleportation effect or the summoning nor the effect's creator or the summoner, but, also, no additional checks beyond what the discovery calls for need be made to make the prevention attempt.

Comment: If the effect is caused by a spell, and the wizard observes the caster, they should get the usual Spellcraft check to identify the spell (and this takes no action): http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/skills/spellcraft.html

Comment: @NeilSlater O, absolutely, but that's nothing to do with the special ability.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Comments removed, and I can fix the title